# vnc server fails to start with I/O Error

Tags: raspbian, server, vnc, raspi-config, raspbian-jessie

I have `Raspberry Pi 2` with `Jessie` raspbian release. I had installed tightvncserver using command -

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
```

Once i had installed the server it was working fine until i restarted my pi. After restarting when i run command to start vnc server using `tightvncserver` command, i get following error -

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tightvncserver
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_GB.UTF-8").
sh: echo: I/O error
Couldn't start Xtightvnc; trying default font path.
Please set correct fontPath in the tightvncserver script.
sh: echo: I/O error
Couldn't start Xtightvnc process.
```

> NOTE: I am getting an I/O Error and there is no issue with creating
>   .vnc file

I couldn't see anybody getting this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/652320/481140) on Ask Ubuntu:

> ```
> Couldn't start Xtightvnc; trying default font path.
> Please set correct fontPath in the vncserver script.
> Couldn't start Xtightvnc process.
> ```
>
> Solution: The x11 fonts are missing, I don't know why the dependency
>   packages are not installed. Try to find folder
>
> ```
> ls /usr/share/fonts/X11/
> ```
>
> if it is not found, then try to install xfonts base
>
> ```
> apt-get install  xfonts-base
> ```

Comment: I tried with this solution. But still i get an I/O error. Not sure whats wrong with my config. I seemed to have messed up my config files. Tightvncserver doesn't start without root permission anymore. Thanks.

Comment: Try removing configuration files, they will reset to defaults and hopefully things will work.

Comment: Sure. will try that. However, i wasn't able to restore `/home/pi/.vnc/xstartup` file. It somehow got deleted. Thanks